# How to (if possible) call an Ember Action in a Javascript procedure or function?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My question is for an Ember Action defined in the same file as the Javascript procedure, in Ember 2.1.

For example, as here where the ember code where we would like to call to myAction outside of the "export" zone:

```
export default Component.extend({
 
  actions: {
    myAction() {
    }
  }
});  

function test(x) {
  CALL TO myAction HERE
  return(3x);
}
```

Comment: if you are asking about calling an action from another action or method, then you can use [`send`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.26/classes/Controller/methods/send?anchor=send) in case if you are using older versions of Ember. If you are using a newer octane model, then you can call the actions as a simple function invocation.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Could you add a code sample?

Comment: Thank you! Gokul Kathirvel, I am using Ember 2.1. jrjohnson, I just added a code sample.

Comment: what will call the `test` function? you'll need a reference to your component instance. you could use a module scope variable, but then you'll need to clean it up. or if you call the `test` function from your ember could I would just pass the component instance as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In modern ember actions are just functions, so you can just call them:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  myFunc() {
    this.myAction(); // this just works
  }

  @action
  myAction() {
  }
}
```

in older embers classic classes there is [`send`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.4/classes/Component/methods/send?anchor=send) or alternatively you can access the action and `.call` it.

```
export default Component.extend({
  myFunc() {
    this.send('myAction'); // this calls the action
    this.actions.myAction.call(this); // this calls the action
  }
  actions: {
    myAction() {
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just wondering if "send" or something equivalent can be used outside from the "export" zone, in order to call an Ember action in a regular, non-Ember javascript function.

Comment: the problem is not some kind of "zone". but this needs more context. what will trigger this code? the problem is you need a reference to the *instance* of the component, not just the class. And ember creates that instance. But you could save the instance to a module scope variable for example. But then you need to make sure to clean up to have no memory leak.